# Collect Directory and Sub Directories with mapping and index in a List<>

Tags: c#, linq, list, collections, directory-structure

I want to collect the directory listing in a collection(a *List<>* perhaps)
my directory structure is like :

```
MainFolder\ParentFolder1\SubFolder1    
                        \SubFolder2    
                        \SubFolder3

MainFolder\ParentFolder2\SubFolder1
                        \SubFolder2
                        \SubFolder3
```

I want to list all the subfolders mapped to their parent directories.

Also, the records will have *index of ParentFolder 0-n in MainFolder* and *index of SubFolder 0-n in each ParentFolder.*

I did tried below but not yet achieved

```
lstParents = (from f in Directory.GetDirectories(MainFolder)
             select  Data
         {
        parent =f
         }).ToList();

var lstSubDir = (from f in lstParents.Select(m => Directory.GetDirectories(m.parent).ToList());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [this overload](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143325(v=vs.110).aspx) of the GetDirectories method to find all subdirectories recursively:

```cs
var mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\MainFolder");
var subDirectories = mainDirectory.GetDirectories("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

Then you can map them into pairs of directory/parent like this:

```cs
var mappedDirectories = subDirectories.Select(sd => new { Parent=sd.Parent, Child=sd });
```

If you want to exclude the first level of subdirectories (`ParentFolder1` and `ParentFolder2`, in your case) you can filter them like this:

```cs
var mappedDirectories = subDirectories
    .Where(sd => sd.Parent.FullName != mainDirectory.FullName)
    .Select(sd => new { Parent=sd.Parent, Child=sd });
```

EDIT after you've asked for indices:

You stated, that you'll always only have a nesting level of 2, the following piece of code will not work for deeper directory structures.

```cs
var mainDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\temp\MainFolder");
var firstLevelDirectories = mainDirectory.GetDirectories().Select((f1,i) => new { 
  Parent = f1, 
  ParentIndex = i 
});

var secondLevelDirectories = firstLevelDirectories
  .SelectMany(f1 => f1.Parent.GetDirectories().Select((f2,i) => new {
    f1.Parent, 
    f1.ParentIndex, 
    Child = f2, 
    ChildIndex = i
} ));
```

This will give you a list of records, each containing

- the parent directory,
- the parent directory index,
- the child directory and
- the child directory index within its parent.

Comment: this is good, i had already tried this. the problem here is MappedDirectories will also have the records for ParentFolder and it's Parent i.e MianFolder. But i only want the records for the SubFolders and there parents.

Comment: I have edited my answer to exclude the first level of sub folders.

Comment: Thanks, also how do i add index to collection using the same Linq,i.e. 0-n for ParentFolders and 0-n for subfolder in one parentfolder.

Comment: So you want one list of records, each giving you a) the parent directory, b) the index of the parent directory, c) the child directory, d) the index of the child directory within its parent?
Also, are you guaranteed to always have only two nesting levels or do you need a solution for possibly deeper paths?

Comment: That's correct. And it's always 2 nested level of directories.

Comment: I have edited my answer to contain a solution for the indices.

Answer (score 0):

Try this recursive algorithm.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Folders folders = new Folders(@"c:\temp", null);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
    public class Folders
    {
        public string path { get; set; }
        List<string> files = new List<string>();
        List<Folders> folders = new List<Folders>();
        Folders parent = null;

        public Folders(string path, Folders parent)
        {
            this.parent = parent;
            this.path = path;
            foreach (string folderPath in Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                Folders newFolder = new Folders(folderPath, this);
                folders.Add(newFolder);
            }
            files = Directory.GetFiles(path).ToList();
            int pathlength = path.Length;
            Boolean first = true;
            Console.Write(path);
            if (files.Count == 0) Console.WriteLine();
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                string shortname = file.Substring(file.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                if (first)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\\" + shortname);
                    first = false;
                }
                else
                {

                    Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', pathlength + 1) + shortname);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
​
```